# Restart Node application on Plesk 17.5 after Git web hook

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, plesk

At the moment I currently have automatic Git deployments set up on a very basic NodeJS server in Plesk 17.5.

The issue is if I push a new commit, I need to login in to the Plesk dashboard manually and click 'Restart Application' otherwise the changes are not live.

I tried adding `npm start` as one of the post-commands on the Git deployment but this doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know how I can automatically restart my Node Application every time there is an automatic deployment from Git? It's not very automated if I have to login and restart the application anyway...

Answer (score 6):

You need to update the modification date of the file `tmp/restart.txt`.

Example with `touch tmp/restart.txt`

- [Phusion Passenger: Node.js tutorial · phusion/passenger Wiki](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/wiki/Phusion-Passenger%3A-Node.js-tutorial#prepare-your-app)

---

With Passenger, you can also execute a command for that: `passenger-config restart-app /Users/phusion/testapp`. But I don't know if it's works with Plesk

- [Restarting application - Apache - Passenger Library](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/admin/apache/restart_app.html#passenger-config-restart-app)

---

Edit:

[Plesk use Phusion Passenger](https://www.plesk.com/blog/product-technology/node-js-plesk-onyx/) to handle Node.js applications.

To use that commands you need to the repository setting and "Enable additional deploy actions" with "Actions". Example: `(PATH=/opt/plesk/node/v9.8.0/bin:$PATH; npm install && npm run build &> npm-install.log) && touch tmp/restart.txt`

Comment: Way too convoluted, and not an answer to the question. Probably Plesk just needs to know the full path of the npm executable. If you're on the cli you can find out where it resides with `which npm`. Also I believe it has a `restart` command aswell. which is more suitable for your situation.

Comment: @OgierSchelvis I edit my answer to clarify why I speak about Phusion Passenger. But touching `tmp/restart.txt` is the only way to restart a Node app in Plesk: "This seemingly strange mechanism comes from the fact that Phusion Passenger is designed to be friendly to shared hosters which only provide FTP access and no SSH access." (see passenger wiki). [npm-restart](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/restart) is not enough for that. Also note that Passenger could use an other NPM version that which one available using `PATH` dirs

Answer (score -2):

Try `/etc/init.d/psa restart`.

I haven't tested it.

[Source](http://forum.odin.com/threads/how-do-i-restart-plesk.48189/)

[Relevant page in official docs](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/12.5/advanced-administration-guide-linux/system-maintenance/restarting-plesk.68620/)

Comment: We are not restarting Plesk server. Just the Node app