# Additional GIT Deployment NPM scripts is not working on Plesk Panel

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, passenger, plesk

i'm running node application on Plesk.

- My GIT integration is running fine.
- My node application is running ifne.

However, I need to execute `npm run build` on my Plesk GIT additional action.

I've tested with solution on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48049405/restart-node-application-on-plesk-17-5-after-git-web-hook) however is not good to go

[image]

My Plesk additional deployment action

`/opt/plesk/node/10/bin/npm run build 2>&1 | tee npm.txt && touch tmp/restart.txt`

I've check and ensure that my Plesk node.js path is `/opt/plesk/node/10/bin/node`

May I know what am i missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our production server is powered via Plesk with Node.js (Passenger/Phusion)

1. You need to login to Plesk Control Panel > Websites & Domains > Web Hosting Access > System User > Ensure that "Access to the server over SSH" is selected as **/bin/bash**
2. Link your GIT with Plesk (Guide at [here](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/website-management/git-support.75824/))
3. On additional deployment action you may paste in below codes

`(PATH=/opt/plesk/node/10/bin:$PATH; npm install && npm run build &> npm.log)
touch tmp/restart.txt`

**Notes**

If you're using node.js version 12 you may change to `/opt/plesk/node/12/bin` instead

touch tmp/restart.txt is a way to restart your Phusion Node.js App since I couldn't restart via `passenger-config restart-app` command

Comment: PATH=/opt/plesk/node/12/bin:$PATH is not working for me, after that I added `npm -v &> teste.log` and it keeps showing 3.5.2

Comment: I was writing each command in one line, so if I need to do an npm command in another line I have to write `PATH=/opt/plesk/node/12/bin:$PATH` again

Comment: How about node -v? Might need to check the available versions on Plesk (https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001630174-Node-js-versions-in-Plesk) and use the correct `node` version to run `npm`

Comment: I realized that I was writing `PATH=/opt/plesk/node/12/bin:$PATH` and `npm -v &> teste.log` on the other line, that way it didn't work, I had to write  `PATH=/opt/plesk/node/12/bin:$PATH && npm -v &> teste.log` in the same line